# Remove TinyMCE skin from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have been searching for a way to completely remove the TinyMCE skin that is applied to the TinyMCE editor in Wordpress. I am using a custom plugin to style up the backend.

Currently I am using `!important` tagged on to the css in order to force my styling to come through - `eg .mce-window-head {background: blue !important;}` which isn't ideal.

I have tried adjusting the priority when using the [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) hook which didn't helped either.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [deregister](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style) the editor-buttons stylesheet like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'so_32482665_remove_editor_buttons_css' );

function so_32482665_remove_editor_buttons_css() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'editor-buttons' );
}
```

[Dequeuing](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) won't work because WordPress doesn't enqueue the stylesheet in the normal way, it prints it out directly with `wp_print_styles()`.

This still leaves you with the default TinyMCE skin though, which looks like it's added in JavaScript so there doesn't appear to be a way to remove it with an action or filter. Whilst it's not considered best practice, outputting the `link` to your stylesheet with the `admin_footer` hook means it'll get loaded after the default skin and will override the styles without having to use `!important`:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'so_32482665_output_custom_editor_css' );

function so_32482665_output_custom_editor_css() {
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/custom-editor.css" type="text/css" />
<?php
}
```

I'd probably use both these approaches, just so you're not fighting with specificity issues from multiple stylesheets.